# Big Bang and where do we stand relative to it?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, big-bang, observable-universe

Maybe dumb question, not sure, but I would need some help here to understand.

https://theglobestalk.com/james-webb-telescope-see-back-in-time/

[image]

So according to physics we can look back in time probably close to the time of big bang with James Webb telescope since light that arrives here from ~14 billion years ago will show us how it was close to the big bang.

The above picture and many more try to explain what the James Webb will try to look for.

But my question is, we live in a 3d space. What if we look in all other infinite positions of our 3d space. We should not be able to see the same history right? I mean if Big Bang started at 1 position of time space and we look that way ok we see ~13.8 billion years before. What if we look the exact opposite direction? We should not be able to see so far right?

The light from the exact opposite direction arriving here should be much less than 13.8 billion years, right? If the history is around the same at all directions around us wouldn't that mean that we are the center of creation and Big Bang ?

Comment: Can you say whether this is essentially a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/
https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25591/  and many other questions along the same lines?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/)

Comment: the above questions not really answer my question directly since what I asked is more specific about how is it supposed to work that we are going to look back into bing bang by looking far enough?

Comment: As the linked answers explain, the Big Bang happened *everywhere*. So you look towards the Big Bang, no matter which direction you look.

Comment: You may think, the universe at the Big Bang was small, but when we look in all directions around, we see space of an enormous size. So how can the small Big Bang appear so huge? This is because space itself acts as a giant telescope magnifying the Big Bang in mind blowing proportions. This question explains the details of how this happens: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/422644/

Comment: “*If the history is around the same at all directions around us wouldn't that mean that we are the center of creation and Big Bang ?*” - When you stand on the surface of the Earth and see the horizon equally in every direction, does this mean you are at the center of the Earth? Not the exact analogy, but conceptually the same idea.